# C++ Camera Roll controls according to global axis, not local axis

Tags: c++, game-engine, directx-11

I am working on a 3D game engine using DX11 and DXMath. Currently i am bussy implementing a camera. The controls work fine for two of the three angles of my camera. yawing and pitching goes fine. However when i try to 'roll' the yaw and pitch controls change only regarding the world space axis, and don't use the new camera axis. As a result, when you roll the camera, and you want to yaw, you would expect it to yaw locally to the camera, right? however it uses the world axis. Does anybody know why this happens? And what i could do to make yaw and pitch relative to the camera's roll?

The two transform variables are the world transform of the camera,  (CT), of which i use the rotation vector to record my rotations,  and the local transform, which is a transform that records the changes on the position of the camera. (Since i have to localize my positions relative to the camera, and as such i cannot simply update the world position) The rotation and scale is not used on this one.

```
Transform CT = Parent.ObjectTransform;
Transform LCT = CurrentCamera.ChangeSinceLastFrame;

XMMATRIX World = GetWorldMatrix(Parent);

XMVECTOR DefaultForward = XMVectorSet(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
XMVECTOR DefaultRight = XMVectorSet(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
XMVECTOR DefaultUp = XMVectorSet(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

XMMATRIX camRotationMatrix = XMMatrixRotationRollPitchYaw(XMConvertToRadians(CT.Rotation.x), XMConvertToRadians(CT.Rotation.y), XMConvertToRadians(CT.Rotation.z));
XMVECTOR camTarget = XMVector3TransformCoord(DefaultForward, camRotationMatrix);
camTarget = XMVector3Normalize(camTarget);

XMVECTOR camRight = XMVector3TransformCoord(DefaultRight, camRotationMatrix);
XMVECTOR camForward = XMVector3TransformCoord(DefaultForward, camRotationMatrix);
XMVECTOR camUp = XMVector3TransformCoord(DefaultUp, camRotationMatrix);

XMVECTOR camPosition = XMVectorSet(CT.Position.x, CT.Position.y, CT.Position.z, 0.0f);

camPosition += LCT.Position.x * camRight;
camPosition += LCT.Position.y * camUp;
camPosition += LCT.Position.z * camForward;

XMFLOAT3 cp;
XMStoreFloat3(&cp, camPosition);

CurrentCamera.ChangeSinceLastFrame = Transform();
CurrentCamera.ChangeSinceLastFrame.Scale = Vector3f();

Parent.ObjectTransform.Position = Vector3f(cp.x, cp.y, cp.z);
camTarget = camPosition + camTarget;

XMMATRIX View = XMMatrixLookAtLH(camPosition, camTarget,camUp);
XMStoreFloat4x4(&ViewMatrix, View);
return View;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, your `XMMatrixRotationRollPitchYaw` does not apply the yaw and pitch rotations locally to the supplied roll angle.
Did you try to explicitly apply the rotations in order, so that you create a rotation matrix for `roll`, `yaw` and `pitch` individually? This way you could concatenate your matrices in an order, where your subsequent yaw and pitch rotations are applied to the rolled frame?

```
XMMATRIX mr = XMMatrixRotationRollPitchYaw(XMConvertToRadians(CT.Rotation.x),0.0, 0.0);
XMMATRIX my = XMMatrixRotationRollPitchYaw(0.0,XMConvertToRadians(CT.Rotation.y), 0.0);
XMMATRIX mp = XMMatrixRotationRollPitchYaw(0.0,0.0,XMConvertToRadians(CT.Rotation.z));
XMMATRIX camRotationMatrix = mr * (mp * my);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a "look at" function is unnecessary if you're positioning the camera with Euler angles. You just need a matrix which transforms from world space to camera space, which is the inverse of the transform you would use if the camera was a regular object.

So after you get `camRotationMatrix`, you can transpose it (to invert the rotation) and translate it to `-CT.Position`. This gives you a matrix that transforms from world space to camera space.

Comment: Before i used the inverse of the world matrix of my camera object. This worked very well, but left me with the problem of how to rotate my camera locally, since setting my camera's x,y,z rotation would be relative to the world instead of my camera. (Which simply sucks for controls then). Currently i am inverstigating quaternions as solution, but i havent yet worked out exactly how to do this. Position is'nt the problem since that's just multiplying a vector with the local changes with the world matrix. However rotations is another story...

Comment: @HindrikStegenga In your previous method, you may have just been applying the rotation in the wrong order. If you rotate before translating, then the rotation is applied around the center of the object (as opposed to the center of the world).

Comment: Currently i am simply taking the inverse of the camera's world matrix as view matrix. It's the same, right? Instead of moving everything relative to the world i move everything relative to the camera. The position of the camera and changing it is not the issue. I currently check how much the camera should move in any direction, transform that point to world space, and set the position of the camera to that. My problem is that we need the rotation in world rotation form. So a rotation of x degrees along the camera's local y axis should change the rotations on the world's axis. How do i convert?